# Get Element ID On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have set up the following function to change the position of the #help Div on load.

```
document.getElementById('help').style.left="600px";
```

How would I make it work on clicking the #help div? (I tried the following)

```
$('#help').click()document.getElementById('help').style.left="600px";)
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why not add the `jquery` tag?

Comment: That last line is a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

Using plain JavaScript you can set the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) event with:

```
document.getElementById("help").onclick = function() {
    this.style.left = "600px";
}
```

Using JQuery you can set the click event with [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method:

```
$("#help").click(function() {
    this.style.left = "600px";
});
```

Comment: @bažmegakapa So this means that I can add multiple events besides changing the position? I went with JQuery just to be safe. 

Now I have to figure out how to add JQuery easing to the function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#help").click(function () {
    $(this).css({
        left: 600
    });
});
```

Edit:
Wrong copy... My bad...

Comment: `$(this)`, not `this`. `css` is a jQuery method.